# Generifying array type such as Object[].class

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to generify following class:

```
public class FooService {

  private Client client;

  public Foo get(Long id) {
    return client.get(id, Foo.class);
  }

  public List<Foo> query() {
    return Arrays.asList(client.get(Foo[].class));
  }

}
```

Everything is alright except `Foo[].class`:

```
public abstract class BaseService<T, I> {

  private Client client;
  private Class<T> type;

  public BaseService(Class<T> type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public T get(I id) {
    return client.get(id, type);
  }

  public List<T> query() {
    return Arrays.asList(client.get(/* What to pass here? */));
  }
```

How can I solve this issue without passing `Foo[].class` in the constructor like I have done with `Foo.class`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java lacks facilities to obtain an array class from element class directly. A common work-around is to obtain the class from a zero-length array:

```
private Class<T> type;
private Class arrType;

public BaseService(Class<T> type) {
    this.type = type;
    arrType = Array.newInstance(type, 0).getClass();
}
```

You can now pass `arrType` to the `client.get(...)` method.

Comment: I thought that too, but then idea warns me and says `Unchecked cast: ...`. Is there a workaround for this as well?

Comment: @s.alem Does it warn you at the point of calling `client.get` or at the point of setting `arrType` in the constructor?

Comment: Sorry, that happens when I set `Class<T[]>`for `arrType`. When I define it as `Class`, it doesn't complain there. However it is say `Unchecked assignment: ...` in the method call `client.get(arrType)`. I can live with that, but it would be cool if there's a workaround.

Comment: @s.alem If you make `arrType` a `Class<T[]>` then you need an explicit cast in front of the assignment, i.e. `arrType = (Class<T[]>)Array.newInstance(type, 0).getClass();` otherwise it wouldn't compile. If this is where Idea complains of unchecked cast, there's little that could be done here, because `getClass` does not pass the actual type of the array. The method is on `java.lang.Object`, so it returns `Class<?>`.

Comment: I suspected that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do something like this:

```
public class Client<T> {

  T instance;

  T get(long id) {
      return instance;
  }

  List<T> get(){
      return new ArrayList<>();
  }
}

class FooService<T> {

  private Client<T> client;

  public T get(Long id) {
      return client.get(id);
  }

  public List<T> query() {
      return client.get();
  }

}
```

Comment: It is probably not visible in this simplified example, but the client is actually out of my reach (3rd party). So this has to be handled in service layer. So in my case wrapping the client with another class only moves the same problem to another layer. But thank you anyway.